# Thinking Outside the Box

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> Think sunburnt capital and Charles the great.
>   Think part of a train with a rather large weight.
>   Think of  a wagon but with what added on.
>   If I amused as I puzzled, that's the art in the con.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> carton

Think sunburnt capital and Charles the great.

> not entirely sure, possibly referring to Corton / Corton-Charlemagne / Burgundy, though this seems like a stretch
>
>  Other possible stretch: Since "great" is not capitalized, you could be referring to Charles Dickens, and this could be referring to Sydney Carton  - Sydney being the capital of NSW which is known for bushfires.

Think part of a train with a rather large weight.

> car + ton = carton

Think of a wagon but with what added on.

> cart + on = carton

If I amused as I puzzled, that's the art in the con.

> **c** *art* **on**

Comment: Think sunburnt capital. - perhaps something to do with Cairo?

Comment: Maybe it's Carson City?

Comment: The title of the riddle is also a fun clue.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Country. Obscure. Teach me not to post as I'm falling asleep.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a little detail. The first line refers to

> Sydney, Australia via the poem [My Country](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Country)

This links to

> Sydney Carton, hero of A Tale Of Two Cities by the "great" Charles Dickens.

I wanted to lead with something tricky since the rest of the puzzle was so straightforward. The rest follows as in the accepted answer.

> A car is part of a train and a ton is a large weight

The third line is a trick of

> Punctuation. A cart is a wagon. With what added? "On."

The last line hammers it home.

> By placing "art" in "con" c(art)on

The title

> Is the only direct reference to the meaning of the word itself.

The whole thing popped into my head as I was falling asleep so I posted as is.